# Server never triggers socket.io connection/listeners until browser reloads the page

Tags: angularjs, express, socket.io

I am getting acquainted with socket.io and I've run into an odd problem. The server never receives the 'connection' event from the client unless the client refreshes the browser.

The expressjs server is simple enough:

```
// server_app.js  =========================

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http)
var socketJwt = require('socketio-jwt');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

....

io.use(socketJwt.authorize({
    secret: 'secret',
    handshake: true
}));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('connection created');

    socket.on("user logged in" function(data) {
        console.log('user logged in');
        // Do stuff with data
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Express app started');
});
```

The client uses AngularJS:

```
// angular_app.js ===========================

var app = angular.module('app', ['ServiceMOdule', 'ngRoute', 'ControllerModule']);

var service_mod = angular.module('ServiceModule', []);
var controller_mod = angular.module('ControllerModule', []);

...
```

My modules for angularjs:

```
// ServiceModule.js =============================

service_mod.factory('FooService',
    function($http) {
        return {

            // Save token
            save: function(){ .... )},

            // Get token
            getToken: function(){ .... },

            // Login POST
            login: function(email, password) {
                return $http.post("/user/login", {"email": email, "password": password});
            }
        }
    }
 });


service_mod.factory('socketService',
    function($rootScope, FooService) {
        var token = FooService.getToken();
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {'query': 'token=' + token });

        console.log('servicesocket called');

        return {

            on: function(eventName, callback) {
                socket.on(eventName, function() {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            },

            emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {

                // Print out the event name to see if this was fired!
                console.log(eventName);

                socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback.apply(socket, args);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
         } 
});




// ControllerModule.js =====================================

controller_mod.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'FooService', 'socketService', function($scope, FooService, socketService) {

    $scope.login = function(email, password) {
        FooService.login(email, password).success(function(data) {
            FooService.save(data['token']);
            socketService.emit('user logged in', {'token': data['token']});
        });
    }
}]);
```

When a user clicks on the login button, angularjs fires `LoginCtrl.login()`, saves the token returned from the login POST, and proceeds to do an `emit()` to notify socket.io that a user has logged in. From the console output in Firebug, I can see the event `user logged in` was printed out. Everything seems swell on the client side.

The problem is, the server never triggers any socket.io listeners. The `io.on('connection', function(socket){...});` never prints out `connection created`. Furthermore, `user logged in` is also never triggered, despite the client calling `emit()` after login.

But! If I reload the browser page, `connection created` **WILL** print out, but `user logged in` is still never triggered because the user is already logged in at this point. The other listeners (not shown here) also trigger fine after an immediate browser refresh after logging in.

Why is this happening and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Shot in the dark but maybe `socketService` isn't invoked until `FooService.login`'s `success` callback is fired. Put a `console.log` in `socketService` before return to see if that's the case.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my post to include the `console.log` after getting the `var socket = io.connect(..);`. In Firebug, I can see that this is called when the login page is loaded and before the user has logged in. I also see the `GET` that socketio makes.